# Sping Boot - download zip file

Tags: spring-boot

When I try to download zip file, it is successfully downloaded, but the download file is named "download.zip", which matched with value parameter of @GetMapping Annotation.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/download", produces = "application/zip")
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getFile() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadDir + "check.zip");
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    }
```

How can I set a specific name for the download file?
Thanks in advance for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should return this as response header : 
`content-disposition : "attachment; filename=check.zip"`

-->

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/download", produces = "application/zip")
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadDir + "check.zip");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=check.zip");
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    }
```